# Dynamic Notifications

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, notifications

I'm trying to make a Xamarin multi platform app with dynamic notifications.

It was an easy way to send notifications using code when user publish news in the app?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use  `Azure Notification Hubs`  to send pushes, so you will be configuring a notification hub for your mobile app.Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push

Comment: @Roberen You mean Push notifications?

Comment: Yes i mean push notifications in app code.

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push .